# embed Pdf File in DLL and then read it

Tags: visual-studio

I want to embed some pdf files in a DLL . I have been made DLL but I can not read it from dll. please help me in this way.

Comment: What language? C#, VB.NET, C++, Boo, IronPython, f#...? Visual Studio is a pretty extensible IDE.

Answer (score 4):

To embed a file in a dll, you need to set the "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource". See the properties of the file in the Solution Explorer.

Then you need to read it as a Stream: `GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name)`,
 where "name" is the full, case sensitive, namespace path of the file, including extension.

Example: The root-namespace of the project is "AA.BB". In there is a folder "CC" where I put the file "file.ext". Then the name would be: "AA.BB.CC.file.ext".